# Lemmatize words inside lists in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

After applying tokenizing, I have a pandas data frame as shown below. I want to apply the nltk lemmatizer in this data frame. What I tried is give here. I am getting error saying '**if form in exceptions:TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'**'. How can I properly implement the lemmatizer here?

Also please note that the 5th data frame cell has an empty list. How can I remove such lists in this data frame?

```
 [[ive, searching, right, words, thank, breather], [i, promise, wont, take, help, granted, fulfil, promise], [you, wonderful, blessing, times]]                     

 [[free, entry, 2, wkly, comp, win, fa, cup, final, tkts, 21st, may, 2005], [text, fa, 87121, receive, entry, questionstd, txt, ratetcs, apply, 08452810075over18s]]

 [[nah, dont, think, goes, usf, lives, around, though]]                                                                                                             

 [[even, brother, like, speak, me], [they, treat, like, aids, patent]]                                                                                              

 [[i, date, sunday, will], []]
```

> The lemmatizer function I tried

```
def lemmatize(fullCorpus):
    lemmatizer = nltk.stem.WordNetLemmatizer()
    lemmatized = fullCorpus['tokenized'].apply(lambda row: list(map([lemmatizer.lemmatize(y) for y in row])))
    return lemmatized
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try as following:

```
def lemmatize(fullCorpus):
    lemmatizer = nltk.stem.WordNetLemmatizer()
    lemmatized = fullCorpus['tokenized'].apply(
            lambda row: list(list(map(lemmatizer.lemmatize,y)) for y in row))
    return lemmatized
```